# IIS served ASP.NET application hangs after serving it about 5-10 times

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, iis, windows-8

I'm serving the app through IIS 8.0 under Windows 8. The site consists of static html and js files which  use ASP.NET Web.Api 2 and SignalR for communication with the server.

Pages load really fast and work fine until I open up multiple instances in ~5-10 tabs, then everything grinds to a halt. Chrome either shows "waiting for *hostname*" or "waiting for available socket".

If I have 4 sucsessfully loaded pages and it hangs trying to load 1 more, I can simply close the other tabs and the last one will load after a short while.

My question is how can I debug this problem, what tools are available to help me find out where the hang is?

Comment: Keep in mind that browser has also connection limit. And opening new tab is not an separated context. Also check the session read-write lock. Try to use Fiddler as sniffer and maybe Selenium and Visual Studio Testing tools like load-test for testing.

Comment: I get the same problem using two different computers, so it's not a browser connection limit. It's as if it never gets to connect to the web-server at all. I'll definitely try to play around with fiddler and check out those other tools. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running IIS in Windows 8, there is a limit of concurrent request, try to host is on a Windows server and you will not have any problems with just a few concurrent requests.

(Cut from the article below for future reference)

**Windows 8 – IIS 8 Concurrent Requests Limit**

Windows 8 (Basic edition)               **3**
Windows 8 Professional, Enterprise  **10**

[IIS concurrent request limits for different versions of Windows](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2012/11/13/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit.aspx)

Comment: This clearly seems to be the issue. Thank you @Mattis!